# Errors when Upgrading to IdentityServer 4.0.2

Tags: identityserver4

Before upgrading, I am successfully able to log in using Azure AD and the local database users (Alice and Bob).
When I upgrade the IdentityServer4 nuget package from 3.1.3 to 4.0.2 and then [upgrade the UI components](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI) using either the power shell command or "dotnet new is4ui", I am able to compile my application.

When I run it, I get the error "Scope  not found in store.". I then add it to the AddInMemoryApiScopes in the Startup method.

When I then run the application, I get "Invalid username or password" when logging in as Alice or Bob. The [demo IdentityServer](https://demo.identityserver.io/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fdiagnostics) no longer permits login for Alice or Bob and gives the same error. When I click the External Account "Azure AD" button, it now throws an "System.Exception: External authentication error".

Are there upgrade notes posted that I am missing when upgrading to the latest version?

Comment: Okay.... I've figured out that the passwords for bob and alice have been changed to "bob" and "alice" respectively. Now identity server  won't redirect back to my application as it used to. I still haven't figured out the External Provider issue.

Comment: Following the Startup for accessing Azure AD from the [demo IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Demo/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4Demo/Startup.cs) I can get a successful login from Azure AD (if I leave out the ValidAudience line) as well but it still won't redirect back to my calling application.

Comment: Also randomly getting a stack overflow exception.

Comment: I followed a great example for [connecting Blazor Server to IdentityServer4](https://mcguirev10.com/2019/12/16/blazor-login-expiration-with-openid-connect.html) where I was able to prove that my local instances work and redirect properly when connecting to the public demo instance of IdentityServer4. The redirection only doesn't work when connecting locally.

Comment: The [template](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Templates) Inserts a default config and startup that does not match the [demo IdentityServer](https://demo.identityserver.io/) in that it retains the line `.AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();` which causes the Local Account authentication to not redirect back to the originating client application. The External  Account authentication is still not redirecting properly.

Comment: Following the demo site's configuration helped resolve the external site not redirecting back to the client application. This issue is now resolved.